# MPMoviePlayerController can't play local file with error _itemFailedToPlayToEnd

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a local iPhone-compatible MP4 video (I've both converted the video for iPhone, and I've tested uploading the video to a web server and entering its URL into mobile Safari, it plays perfectly) that I want to play using `MPMoviePlayerController`.

Here is my code:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Welcome" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath];
playerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
playerController.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
playerController.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

playerController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
playerController.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
//[playerController.view setFrame:moviePlayerContainerView.frame];
[playerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
[moviePlayerContainerView addSubview:playerController.view];
playerController.contentURL = fileURL;
playerController.fullscreen = YES;
[playerController prepareToPlay];
[playerController play];
```

`fileURL` points to a valid file:

```
(lldb) po fileURL
/var/mobile/Applications/73C97CC9-731E-4446-A53C-2A8CA30A2393/Tanisalim.app/Welcome.mp4
(lldb) p (BOOL)[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath isDirectory:NO]
(BOOL) $0 = YES
```

When I try to run on simulator (both 6.1 and 7.1), it just displays a black screen in frame (if fullscreen is `NO`) or opens a movie player view controller and stays forever "Loading...". When I run on device (iOS 7.1), the behavior is the same, but I'm getting this error on the console:

```
_itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {
    kind = 1;
    new = 2;
    old = 0;
}
```

When I try to load the exact same video file to stream from web directly, it works perfectly:

```
//playerController.contentURL = fileURL;
playerController.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mywebsite.com/Welcome.mp4"];
```

I've tried different video files but the result is the same. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9):

I had the exact same problem, but it was multi-layered in my case.

- Make sure that you're using `-fileURLWithPath:` and not `-URLWithString:` to create your URL, as @tagy22 mentioned. Seems like that does the job for many, however I was already using a file URL, so something was missing.
- Make sure your local file has an extension (".mp4", for example). `MPMoviePlayerController` doesn't like files without an extension. A solution if you need to store files without an extension is to create a temporary symlink to the actual file and give `MPMoviePlayerController` the file URL to that symlink instead of the "real" file.
- Your symlink should be located somewhere in the iOS *Caches* directory (~/Library/Caches), else it might not work. I was trying to have `MPMoviePlayerController` play a symlink that was in the temp directory and it worked in the Simulator but **not** on my devices.

### Creating a symlink to the actual video file

```
NSError *error;
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[manager createSymbolicLinkAtURL:linkPath withDestinationURL:actualFilePath error:&error];
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me - I had to add an ".mp4" when saving and loading

Comment: Thank you for the note on it having to be in the Caches directory - I genuinely thought I was going crazy (I, in my foolishness, also created the symlink in the temp directory instead of the caches directory).

Comment: @AlexStone For me the symlink creation returns true, but the MPMoviePlayerViewController throws error 'Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory'. Any clue ? Is there a way i can confirm that the symlink exists apart from the return value of the createSymbolicLinkAtURL method ?

Comment: @geekoraul Hard to say but I'd double-check the **absolute** paths for both symlink creation and when reading the file to make sure they are the same, and that both are file URLs. You can also check if the symlink exists using NSFileManager.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem, streaming files worked fine but could not play local files. The following change solved it for me:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath];
```

to:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
```

Comment: That is certainly a valuable insight.

Comment: Actually the whole problem could have been avoided if the the OP had called `URLForResource:withExtension:` to start with - i.e., obtain an NSURL up front, instead of getting an NSString and converting (wrongly) to an NSURL.